# Using OkHttp inside Liferay to consume external rest APIs. Problem with OSGi

Tags: java, rest, build.gradle, liferay, osgi

Inside a gradle java Liferay REST API backend (created with blade create -t rest), we are trying to use an OkHttp client from within Liferay 7.2 to access another rest API which is external.

The build.gradle dependencies include this line :

```
implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.9.0'
```

The build goes ok, but when we deploy the jar to the Liferay server, we got an error that says :

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: backendapp [1177]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: okhttp3_ [Sanitized]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
```

Is OkHttp OSGI-ready for Liferay? and if not what is an LR-friendly alternative to consume rest APIs from inside a java inside LR?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming OkHttp is delivered as a valid OSGi bundle: just building your plugin doesn't make its dependencies available to the runtime. You'll have to deploy it (and it's dependencies) to the runtime separately to make it available.

Of course this needs to happen just once, not every time you update your own plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the external jars within your jar if not using for other plugins. please follow [how to included non osgi jar in to Liferay modules](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2020/03/adding-third-party-non-osgi-jars-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can add in below dependency in build.gradle

```
compileInclude group: "com.squareup.retrofit2", name: "retrofit", version: "2.5.0"
compileInclude group: "com.squareup.retrofit2", name: "converter-jackson", version: "2.5.0"
compileInclude group: 'org.cache2k', name: 'cache2k-all', version: '1.0.2.Final'
compileInclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.2.2'
```

Also you need to add below lines in bnd.bnd file

```
Import-Package: \
!android.*,\
!com.android.*,\
!dalvik.system,\
!javax.annotation.meta,\
!kotlin.internal.jdk7,\
!kotlin.internal.jdk8,\
!kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal,\
!org.conscrypt,\
!org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl,\
!org.openjsse.net.ssl,\
!org.xmlpull.v1,\
!sun.security.ssl,\
*
```

Hope it works for you.